# How to integrate $\cos \left(\frac{y-x}{y+x}\right)$?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

Suppose $D$ is a trapezoid with vertices $(0, 1)$, $(1, 0)$, $(0, 2)$, $(2, 0)$. How to calculate the following?

$$\iint_D \cos \left(\frac{y-x}{y+x}\right) \, \mathrm d x \mathrm d y$$

**P.S.**

Thanks a lot to Robert Z, I solved the problem now. My solution is this:
$$u=y-x$$
$$v=y+x$$
$$\iint_Dcos(\frac{y-x}{y+x})dxdy = \int_1^2 \int_{-v}^v \cos(\frac{u}{v}) du dv = \int_1^2 2v\sin(1) dv = 3\sin(1)$$

Comment: What effort have you put in?

Comment: Besides that needed to type the problem into MathJax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint. Let $u=y−x$ and $v=x+y$. Then
$$\iint_D \cos \left(\frac{y-x}{y+x}\right) \, d x d y=\iint_T \cos \left(\frac{u}{v}\right) \, J(u,v)d u d v.$$
What is the new domain of integration $T$. What is $J(u,v)$? Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thanks a lot! The secret is to change the variables :).

Comment: Can I send my answer to you to check it?

Comment: Sure. Show your efforts under your question: "My work. ...."

Comment: I've added the solution. Can you please check it now?

Comment: @EhsanPoursaeed Have you considered the Jacobian of the transformation?

Comment: No. I don't know what Jacobian is. I'll read about it later but for now I don't know what's wrong with my answer. I'm thinking now :).

Comment: You just forget the Jacobian determinant that in this case is a constant. The rest of your solution is correct. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant It's crucial for change of variables in multiple integrals

Comment: Thanks a lot :). I'll read about it.

Answer (score 0):

I think I would have preferred listing the points of the vertices of the trapezoid in the order $(0,1), (1,0), (2,0), (0,2)$

Sketch the regoin you'll see this [image: trapezoid]

Note the top is $x+y=2$ and the bottom is $x+y=1$

So you can evaluate the integral by one of the following

$$\int_1^2\int_{1-x}^{2-x} \cos \left(\frac{y-x}{y+x}\right) dydx$$

$$\int_1^2\int_{1-y}^{2-y} \cos \left(\frac{y-x}{y+x}\right) dxdy$$

Unfortunately neither of those is particularly easy to evaluate the antiderivative. So consider the transformation $u=y-x$ and $v=y+x$

This transforms the points to $(1,1),(−1,1),(−2,2),(2,2)$ and the 
region to what we'll call $R$ below [image: trap]

The Jacobian $J(u,v)=
\begin{bmatrix} \partial u/ \partial x & \partial u/ \partial y \\
 \partial v/ \partial x & \partial v/ \partial y \\
\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix} -1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}
$

Has $|J(u,v)|=-2$

So your integral becomes $$\iint_R \cos\left(\frac{u}{v}\right) (-2) dA$$

It looks a little messy since you'll need 3 different parts if you want to do it in rectangular coordinates. Polar coordinates might give some fun options but I haven't worked them through.